# How to fix the DB calls exception - ERROR: Cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction in Spring boot JPA

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am facing the below error when doing insert/updates/deletes using Spring Boot -JPA

when executing the Postgres calls?

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException : could not execute statement ; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenereircJDBCException : Could not execute statement with root cause org.postgreql.util.PSQLException: ERROR cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction

The application is kind of modeled along the lines as in

https://springframework.guru/how-to-configure-multiple-data-sources-in-a-spring-boot-application/

I am using the below stack

Spring boot - 2.2.7.RELEASE
JPA 2.0

This is a multidatasource application and i can't make any changes at the DB server.
Are there any changes that we can do at the java code end to fix the issue.

Regards

Comment: Please show your controller and repository classes.

Comment: @oxygenan please show the code for repo/model/service classes, did you by any chance mark the repo/model/service classes/methods as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`??